# Fetching date from Mongodb database and Showing it in jade file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want to fetch all the date from MongoDB database but I want to show the date only one time means date should not be repeated, i.e. grouped by day,month and year.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var chatSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    nick: String,
    msg: String,
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
var chat = mongoose.model('Message', chatSchema);
app.get('/history/chats', function(req, res){
    chat.find({group: "created"}, function(err, docs){
        res.render('history', {users: docs});
    });
});
```

and in jade file

```
tbody
 each user in users
  tr
   td
    a(href='../info/chats') #{user.created.getMonth()}/#{user.created.getDate()}/#{user.created.getFullYear()}
```

and after using 'group', I am not getting the required answer.
means if

Answer (score 0):

Right now that query is looking for documents where `group = "created"`, it's not doing any grouping at all. As such, it's not finding any documents.

If you want to group by day/month/year, you'll need to use the MongoDB [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/).

Some other resources:

- [`$group` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)
- [Date operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/)

For example, to group by day in Mongoose, you'll need to write some code like:

```
chat.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      day: { $dayOfYear: "$created" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
], function (err, result) {
  // do stuff with your result
});
```

The above counts the number of docs by day of the year. If you want to get the full docs grouped by day, use the [`$$ROOT`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-documents-by-author) operator.

**Note:** it's advisable to use a [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) step before a `$group` to minimise the query time.